# Correct use of the EntityManager in an @Async call

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am trying to use the `@Async` capabilities of the Spring framework to perform a simple indexing task.

The problem I'm facing is that I feel that the `EntityManager` used in my Async function is somehow reused from previous calls so my data is not up to date and sometimes uses old data.

Here is the code I wrote as an example. The goal is to update a product's data and index it asynchronously after I publish an event using Spring's `ApplicationEventPublisher`:

**ProductService**

```
@Service
class ProductService {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @Autowired
    public ProductService(EntityManager entityManager, ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void patchProduct (String id, ProductDto productDto) {
        Product product = this.entityManager.find(Product.class, id);
        product.setLabel(productDto.getLabel());
        this.entityManager.flush();
        this.eventPublisher.publishEvent(new ProductEvent(product, ProductEvent.EVENT_TYPE.UPDATED));
    }
}
```

**EventListener**

```
@Component
public class ProductEventListener {

    private final AsyncProcesses asyncProcesses;

    @Autowired
    public ProductEventListener (
        AsyncProcesses asyncProcesses
    ) {
        this.asyncProcesses = asyncProcesses;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void indexProduct (ProductEvent productEvent) {
        this.asyncProcesses.indexProduct(productEvent.getProduct().getPok());
    }
}
```

**AsyncProcesses**

```
@Service
public class AsyncProcesses {

    private final SlowProcesses slowProcesses;

    @Autowired
    public AsyncProcesses(SlowProcesses slowProcesses) {
        this.slowProcesses = slowProcesses;
    }

    @Async
    public void indexProduct (String id) {
        this.slowProcesses.indexProduct(id);
    }
}
```

**SlowProcesses**

```
@Service
public class SlowProcesses {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private ProductSearchService productSearchService;

    @Autowired
    public SlowProcesses(EntityManager entityManager, NewProductSearchService newProductSearchService) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.newProductSearchService = newProductSearchService;
    }

    @Transactional(readonly = true)
    public void indexProduct (String pok) {
        Product product = this.entityManager.find(Product.class, pok);
        // this.entityManager.refresh(product); -> If I uncomment this line, everything works as expected
        this.productSearchService.indexProduct(product);
    }
}
```

As you can see on the **SlowProcesses** file, if I refresh the product object in the entityManager, I get the correct and up to date data. If I do not, I might get old data from previous calls.

**What is the correct way to use the EntityManager in an Asynchronous call? Do I really have to refresh all my objects in order to make everything work? Am I doing something else wrong?**

Thank you for reading through

Comment: EntityManager instances are not threadsafe. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqy/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Since instances of EntityManager are not thread-safe as pointed out by Jordie, you may want to try this instead:
Instead of injecting an EntityManager, inject an EntityManagerFactory. Then from the EntityManagerFactory retrieve a new EntityManager instance that is used only for the duration of the method in question.